# Moving a memory layer in the TOC using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, memory-layer

I've got a layer (`difflayer`) that has been created in memory. Basically, all the layers I've got in this project are in memory and the layer creation/manipulation is all being handled via a plugin.

Now, from looking around it seems the best way to move a layer around is to `clone()` it, use `insertChildNode` to add the clone, and then delete the original. Which I'd have no problem doing, except that layers in memory don't support `clone()`.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've also tried to duplicate the layer using the below code but get the following error:

```
feats = [feat for feat in difflayer.getFeatures()]
mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:4283&field=ID:integer", "dup layer", "memory")
mem_layer_data = mem_layer.dataProvider()
attr = difflayer.dataProvider().fields().toList()
mem_layer_data.addAttributes(attr)
mem_layer.updateFields()
mem_layer_data.addFeatures(feats)
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
root.insertChildNode(2,mem_layer)
```

`TypeError: QgsLayerTreeGroup.insertChildNode(int, QgsLayerTreeNode): argument 2 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'`

Comment: Is your question _"why does this code snippet doesn't work"_ ? Did you correct the syntax error of the last line ? Did you check the difference between **QgsLayerTreeNode** and **QgsVectorLayer** in the API ?

Comment: You need to use  'insertLayer' method of **QgsLayerTreeGroup** instead 'insertChildNode' method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **TypeError** is correct: argument 2 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'. It can be easily corroborated with help(QgsLayerTreeGroup.insertChildNode).

So, I used following code for creating a memory layer:

```
point = QgsPointXY(395065.34243502904, 4443021.813507973)

epsg = 32612

uri = "Point?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'point',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feat = QgsFeature()

feat.setAttributes([0])
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(point))

prov.addFeature(feat)

registry = QgsProject.instance()

registry.addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

and I loaded three additional layers to Map View of QGIS. Group looks as follows; where point is a memory layer.

[image]

Following code pretends to 'clone' point memory layer (layers[0]) between **polygon8** and **random** layers. However, 'insertLayer' method of **QgsLayerTreeGroup** is used instead 'insertChildNode' (because in the first case argument 2 can be of type 'QgsVectorLayer').

```
registry = QgsProject.instance()

layers = list(registry.mapLayers().values())

root = registry.layerTreeRoot()

root.insertLayer(3, layers[0])
```

After running above code, result was as expected; as it can be corroborated in following image. So, memory does support methods of **QgsLayerTreeGroup**.

[image]

Comment: This works, though I neglected to mention I was using QGIS 2.18. So `layers = list(registry.mapLayers().values())` becomes `layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()`